# Center all equations inside align

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

i want to center these equations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
        \begin{align} \label{eq:test}
            \sum {i=1}ˆ{5} x i & = 15 \\
            xˆ2 + 10 x + 200 & = 0 \\
            A&=AAA\\
            B&=BBB\\
        \end{align}
\end{document}
```

I want them these four equations to be treaten like a figure (so center them without losing the alignment). 
I saw many thread but all seem to be different (e.g. most only want to center one equation)

Thank you for your kind help.

edit1:
That's what i get if i use it inside my real document:
[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand, aren't they centered? (Unrelated: don't end the last line of an `align` with ```\\```.)

Comment: @himynameis, your MWE gives the equations centered. You have to add things (definitions and packages) that possibly change the result like your photo until you get the same output. If the particular MWE gives the photo you uploaded there is something wrong with your version...

Comment: Probably you have `fleqn` somewhere, either in the options to the class, or to the `amsmath` package.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. you are right. i have to use a template. What is `fleqn` used for? Are there consequences if i remove it?

Comment: The only consequence is that all your displayed equations will be centered. `fleqn` = flush left equations.

Comment: ah that's perfect thank you. if i could i'd vote for you :)